# Angular $scope and ng-if/ng-show issue. Status not changing in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am using Firebase for authentication on my web app. I have buttons on the different pages that I only want to appear if the admin is logged in. I've been trying to use ng-if on the button to show if loggedin = true. I've console logged the stated of 'loggedin' and it appears to be changing correctly, but the buttons simply do not show up.

I can't figure out what is happening here for the life of me. I've checked out the angular docs reading about $scope, the ngIf, and ngShow directives, but nothing is clicking for me. I also reviewed [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904074/firebase-checking-if-user-is-logged-in) which shows where this process came from in the first place. It appears to be working for the people in that thread, but no joy for me.

This is the code in my controller:

```
app.controller('welcomeCtrl', function ($scope, welcomeData, $routeParams, $location) {

var ref = new Firebase('https://mywebapp.firebaseio.com/');

  //authentication check
  var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function (error, user) {
    if (error) {
      // an error occurred while attempting login
      console.log(error);
    }
    // no user logged in
     else if (user === null) {
      console.log("Not logged in");
    }
    // normal user logged in
    else if (user.id !== "47f0b82c-59d2-4bcd-8arc-ecb438eb0163") {
      console.log("You are logged in as normal user");
    }
    // admin logged in
    else {
      console.log("Logged in as admin");
      $scope.loggedin = true;
      console.log("logging the scope.loggedin as admin " + $scope.loggedin);
    }
  });

  $scope.loggedin = false;
  console.log("logging scope.loggedin " + $scope.loggedin);

  var authCheck = function () {
    console.log("logging the scope in authCheck " + $scope.loggedin);
    return auth.user !== null;
  };
  authCheck();
```

This is the HTML element that doesn't seem to be changing appropriately:

```
<div ng-show="loggedin">
  <a class="btn waves-effect waves-red" ng-href="/#/editWelcome/{{welcome._id}}">Update
  </a>
</div>
```

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly? Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is your `auth` object's callback actually called?  I see that it's initialized, but unless your `FirebaseSimpleLogin` constructor calls it then `$scope.loggedin` is never set to `true`.

Comment: maybe, you try to put $scope.$apply() inside of FirebaseSimpleLogin(){... //here}

Comment: $scope.$apply() worked!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, FirebaseSimpleLogin is deprecated. The auth methods are now part of the core Firebase library. You can use the [`onAuth`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/onauth.html) callback for your implementation.

The reason you're not seeing your `$scope.loggedin` value change is because Firebase's callbacks happen outside of Angular's digest scope. You need to tell Angular about this change by either using [`$scope.$evalAsync()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync)  or Firebase's own AngularFire library.

To use $evalAsync, in your last else block wrap your $scope changes in a function like so:

```
    // admin logged in
    else {
      console.log("Logged in as admin");
      $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
         $scope.loggedin = true;
      });
    }
```

Comment: ☃. When working with services, it can be handy to use `$timeout()` in place of `$scope` (which may not be available to the service). Alternately, `$rootScope.$evalAsync()` works, too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sherali Turdiyev for the answer to this problem.

```
 //authentication check
 var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function (error, user) {
if (error) {
  // an error occurred while attempting login
  console.log(error);
}
// no user logged in
 else if (user === null) {
  console.log("Not logged in");
}
// normal user logged in
else if (user.id !== "47f0b82c-59d2-4bcd-8arc-ecb438eb0163") {
  console.log("You are logged in as normal user");
}
// admin logged in
else {
  console.log("Logged in as admin");
  $scope.loggedin = true;
  console.log("logging the scope.loggedin as admin " + $scope.loggedin);
}
// this resolved the issue
$scope.$apply();
 });
```

After [reading the documentation for $scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) I discovered that this is an issue with the digest cycle. The $scope.$apply() forces the digest which updates the scope. Additionally, I discovered that I shouldn't be doing this in the controller. Time to turn this in to a directive. Thanks again fort he help!